# Investigate if ActiveRecord Connection Pool in Ruby process leak Pool

Tags: ruby, oracle, activerecord, oracle11g

I have configured database.yml as below

```
development:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  host: 10.80.70.58
  port: 1521
  database: TTSDB
  username: TTSADMIN
  password: xxxxx
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 20
```

I have spawned ruby processes which give me error for connection timeout
`[ExceptionHandler] Exception ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.029 seconds)` I have 8 of these ruby processes which does some computation, these processes use the configuration from database.yml.

Now when I see sessions in v$session among 78 sessions I find, 71 are `INACTIVE` and only 7 are in `ACTIVE`. I found out this number from 
the query is given below

`select count(*) from v$session where schema name = 'TTSADMIN' and osuser = 'tuts0001' and status = 'INACTIVE'`

Now the question

1. Does my ruby process leaking ActiveRecord::Connection pool(as described in this [link](https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/activerecord-concurrency-in-rails4-avoid-leaked-connections/)), due to which I do not have any connection in ActiverecordConnectionPool which is why I am receiving connection timeout error?
2. If Not Why am I seeing 71 sessions `INVALID` in `v$session` table? I have checked the docs from this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/REFRN/dynviews_3016.htm#REFRN30223)